# Create or replace function sql - replace all instance of string with NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to replace all instance of a string in my table with NULL. I would rather not go column by column since I have several tables with 30 columns each to do.

Here is what I have tried:

```
create or replace function f2(_table text,_oldVal text,_newVal text) returns void as 
$$
declare 
rw record;
begin
for rw in 
    select 'UPDATE '||$1||' SET '||C.COLUMN_NAME||' = REPLACE ('||C.COLUMN_NAME||','''||$2||''','''||$3||'''); ' QRY
    FROM (select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema='public' and     table_name =$1)c
loop
    EXECUTE rw.QRY;
end loop;
end;
$$language plpgsql;

SELECT f2('eavs2014','-999999NA', '');
```

This replaces it with a blank instead of NULL which is not appropriate for what I need.

Using NULL as the third argument of my call statement throws and error:
SELECT f2('eavs2014','-999999NA', NULL);

ERROR:  query string argument of EXECUTE is null
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function f2(text,text,text) line 9 at EXECUTE
SQL state: 22004

I tried rewriting the function with the NULL inside the function instead of the call.

```
create or replace function f2(_table text,_oldVal text) returns void as 
$$
declare 
rw record;
begin
for rw in 
    select 'UPDATE '||$1||' SET '||C.COLUMN_NAME||' = REPLACE ('||C.COLUMN_NAME||','''||$2||''', NULL); ' QRY
    FROM (select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema='public' and     table_name =$1)c
loop
    EXECUTE rw.QRY;
end loop;
end;
$$language plpgsql;

SELECT f2('eavs2014','-999999NA');
```

This just filled the entire table with NULL - not just the -999999NA

I've tried several other iterations of this function as well, but none have worked. Can anyone help me troubleshoot my function to replace all strings of '-999999NA' with NULL?

Comment: You failed to describe how you are calling that function.

Comment: Please update the post with a [mre]. Include a sample input table and expected output. Please include sufficient cases make the destired behavior unambiguous. Is the intent to replace '-999999NA' with NULL only when it is the entire string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a function that will perform the described operation (the `RAISE NOTICE` statement is only included to output the generated SQL statement for demonstration purposes):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f2(_table text, _old_val text, _new_val text) RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$FUNC$
<<local>>
DECLARE
  criteria         text;
  match_phrase     text;
  set_list         text;
  update_statement text;
BEGIN
  IF _old_val IS NOT DISTINCT FROM _new_val THEN
    RETURN;
  END IF;
  
  match_phrase = CASE WHEN _old_val IS NULL THEN 'IS NULL' ELSE FORMAT($$= %L$$, _old_val) END;

  SELECT STRING_AGG(FORMAT($$%1$I = CASE WHEN %1$I %2$s THEN %3$s ELSE %1$I END$$,
                           c.column_name,
                           local.match_phrase,
                           CASE WHEN f2._new_val IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE QUOTE_LITERAL(f2._new_val) END),
                    ', ' ORDER BY c.ordinal_position),
         STRING_AGG(FORMAT($$%1$I %2$s$$, c.column_name, local.match_phrase),
                    ' OR ' ORDER BY c.ordinal_position)
    INTO set_list, criteria
    FROM information_schema.columns c
    WHERE c.table_schema = CURRENT_SCHEMA()
      AND c.table_name = f2._table
      AND c.data_type IN ('char', 'character', 'character varying', 'text');
  
  update_statement = FORMAT($$UPDATE %1$I SET %2$s WHERE %3$s;$$, _table, set_list, criteria);
  
  RAISE NOTICE 'Update statement: %', update_statement;
  
  EXECUTE update_statement;
END;
$FUNC$;
```

If `_old_val` and `_new_val` are the same, then the function exits without executing any queries. Updates are only performed on rows where at least one of the columns has the criteria value. These two design decisions prevent the creation of dead tuples. Only character columns are evaluated, which avoids potential issues with attempting to cast values with invalid syntax for the target type.

The following demonstrates the function's use:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS f2_tests;

CREATE TABLE f2_tests(
  id INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  c1 text,
  c2 text);

INSERT INTO f2_tests(c1, c2)
VALUES ('-999999NA', '-999999NA'),
       ('Kept', '-999999NA'),
       ('-999999NA', 'Kept'),
       ('Kept', 'Kept');

SELECT f2('f2_tests', '-999999NA', NULL);

SELECT *
  FROM f2_tests
  ORDER BY id;
```

The resulting output is:

| id | c1 | c2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [null] | [null] |
| 2 | Kept | [null] |
| 3 | [null] | Kept |
| 4 | Kept | Kept |

Comment: Thank you. For some reason, I'm getting this error when I try to run this function.  Any idea what part might be producing this error?

ERROR:  cannot change name of input parameter "_oldval"
HINT:  Use DROP FUNCTION f2(text,text,text) first.
SQL state: 42P13

Comment: @exumablue, in your original version the parameters where named `_oldval` and `_newval`. When I created the function, I added an `_` between the syllables. The parameter names can't be changed using `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION...`. Either remove the added `_` from the parameter names in my version or drop the function using the syntax in the error message's hint and then use my version.